# Adding a link on the Django Admin frontpage

Tags: django, django-admin

I've created a custom view to make some data entry easier and I want to add a link to it on the front page of the Django admin. Is there an easy way to do this?

I suppose I could override the default admin template, but before I do that I just want to make sure there isn't something simpler I could do.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing simpler: override the template :)